# Size operator in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network

In the classification of samples using neural network if we specify the number of testing samples by the command

```
N = size(testInputs,2);
```

what does the value 2 indicate? how does it affect the number of test samples?

Comment: See: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html

Comment: Oh, come on. If you read the first few lines of text in the first Google result of "Matlab size" you'll find the meaning. It took me more time to type this than to do that

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about neural network but in Matlab if we write the code

```
N = size(testInputs,2);
```

This returns the number of columns of the testInputs matrix. Alternatively if you consider the testInputs to be a multi-dimensional array - it should give you the length of the second dimension of that particular array.

Please check my code snippet.

```
>> A=rand(3,2)

A =

    0.1009    0.4430
    0.8758    0.2070
    0.7295    0.1554

>> size(A,2)

ans =

     2
```

I hope this helps.